# i3 - Shortcuts using bind with multiple keycodes

Tags: linux, user-interface, desktop, i3

I want to add a custom shortcut to i3 desktop in linux.The manual says you should use `bind [Modifiers+]keycode` command.
Commands with just one keycode(gotten from `xev`) work fine but I don't know how to use multiple keycodes(e.g for $mod+alt+up).Also there is no modifier for `Alt` key that I can use in conjunction with `bindsym`.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The `Alt` key is specified by the `Mod1` identifier. Therefore you can do:
Super + Alt + q by

```
$mod+Mod1+q
```

where `$mod` is defined earlier in the config as `Mod4` or

```
Mod4+Mod1+q
```

Comment: Thanks , that works nicely . but I wanted to use `bind` since I didn't know any symbol for `+` key in numpad.Is there a way to use multiple keycodes?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3053/how-do-i-change-workspace-with-the-numeric-pad.1.html

Comment: That solved the problem,thanks.